# When would I use mapc instead of mapcar?

Tags: dictionary, lisp, common-lisp

So far I have been using `mapcar` to apply a function to all elements of a list, such as:

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) (* x x))
        '(1 2 3 4 5))
;; => '(1 4 9 16 25)
```

Now I learned that there is also the `mapc` function which does exactly the same, but does not return a new list, but the original one:

```
(mapc (lambda (x) (* x x))
      '(1 2 3 4 5))
;; => '(1 2 3 4 5)
```

What's the intent of this function? When would I use `mapc` instead of `mapcar` if I am not able to access the result?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Common Lisp Hyperspec says:

`mapc` is like `mapcar` except that the results of applying function are not accumulated. The list argument is returned.

So it is used when mapping is done for possible side-effects. `mapcar` could be used, but `mapc` reduces unnecessary consing. Also its return value is the original list, which could be used as input to another function.

Example:

```
(mapc #'delete-file (mapc #'compile-file '("foo.lisp" "bar.lisp")))
```

Above would first compile the source files and then delete the source files. Thus the compiled files would remain.

```
(mapc #'delete-file (mapcar #'compile-file '("foo.lisp" "bar.lisp")))
```

Above would first compile the source files and then delete the compiled files.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `mapc` when you don't need to use the result of applying the function over the list. For example, to print out every element, you could use:

```
(mapc #'print '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

Technically, the `print` function will return something, but you don't need to use it, so you ignore it.

Comment: Ah, okay :-)). But it wouldn't be wrong if I used `mapcar` here as well, would it?

Comment: The only time I can think of where it would make a difference is if it were the last statement in a function or a `progn`, as the result from that would be returned. But otherwise, yeah, it wouldn't be wrong.

Comment: @GoloRoden The code won't do the wrong thing if you used `mapcar`, but people who look at your code will scratch their head and wonder why you didn't use `mapc` instead, if the return value is not used. (In Scheme, the situation is a little different: `for-each` (Scheme analogue to `mapc`) calls your function on list elements left-to-right, whereas `map` (Scheme analogue to `mapcar`) does not specify an order (many implementations actually use right-to-left), so you should only use `map` for pure functions.)